# How efficiently check record exist more than 2 times in table using sub-query?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a query like this . I have compound index  for CC.key1,CC.key2.
I am executing this in a big database

```
Select * from CC where 

 (  (
    (select count(*) from Service s 
            where CC.key1=s.sr2 and CC.key2=s.sr1) > 2
     AND
     CC.key3='new'
    ) 
 OR 
    (
    (select count(*) from Service s 
            where CC.key1=s.sr2 and CC.key2=s.sr1) <= 2
    )
     )
limit 10000;
```

I tried to make it as inner join , but its getting slower . How can i optimize this query ?

Answer (score 2):

The trick here is being able to articulate a query for the problem:

```
SELECT *
FROM CC t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT cc.key1, cc.key2
    FROM CC cc
    LEFT JOIN Service s
        ON cc.key1 = s.sr2 AND
           cc.key2 = s.sr1
    GROUP BY cc.key1, cc.key2
    HAVING COUNT(*) <= 2 OR
           SUM(CASE WHEN cc.key = 'new' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 2
) t2
    ON t1.key1 = t2.key1 AND
       t1.key2 = t2.key2
```

**Explanation:**

Your original two subqueries would only add to the count if a given record in `CC`, with a given `key1` and `key2` value, matched to a corresponding record in the `Service` table.  The strategy behind my inner query is to use `GROUP BY` to count the number of times that this happens, and use this instead of your subqueries.  The first count condition is your bottom subquery, and the second one is the top.

The inner query finds all `key1`, `key2` pairs in `CC` corresponding to records which should be retained.  And recognize that these two columns are the only criteria in your original query for determining whether a record from `CC` gets retained.  Then, this inner query can be inner joined to `CC` again to get your final result set.

In terms of performance, even this answer could leave something to be desired, but it should be better than a massive correlated subquery, which is what you had.

Comment: Didn't get much improvement in speed, Could you tell me what index should i use for "cc". now  query not using any index

Comment: Do you have indices on `key1`, `key2`, `sr1` and `sr2`?

Comment: i have  " INDEX `service_index` (`sr2`, `sr1`)"

Comment: should i create index for CC  like 
"INDEX cc_index (key1, key2)"

Comment: @E-ebolavirus Could you try that?

Comment: tried, but query not using that index, getting NULL in "possible keys" column of explain result

Comment: Hmmm...I was hoping that the inner `LEFT JOIN` query would benefit from an index.

Answer (score 0):

Basically get the Columns that must not have a duplicate then join them together. Example:

```
select  *
FROM    Table_X A
WHERE   exists (SELECT 1
                FROM   Table_X B
                WHERE  1=1
                 and    a.SHOULD_BE_UNIQUE = b.SHOULD_BE_UNIQUE
                 and    a.SHOULD_BE_UNIQUE2 = b.SHOULD_BE_UNIQUE2
                 /* excluded because these columns are null or can be Duplicated*/
                 --and    a.GENERIC_COLUMN = b.GENERIC_COLUMN
                 --and    a.GENERIC_COLUMN2 = b.GENERIC_COLUMN2
                 --and    a.NULL_COLUMN = b.NULL_COLUMN
                 --and    a.NULL_COLUMN2 = b.NULL_COLUMN2
                 and      b.rowid > a.ROWID);
```

Where SHOULD_BE_UNIQUE and SHOULD_BE_UNIQUE2 are columns that shouldn't be repeated and have unique columns and the GENERIC_COLUMN and NULL_COLUMNS can be ignored so just leave them out of the query.

Been using this approach when we have issues in Duplicate Records.

Comment: I recommend you study Tim's answer...This doesn't answer the question at all. And there's no `NVL()` in MySQL afaik.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that MySQL has no `code`NVL()`code` @fancyPants

Answer (score 0):

With the limited information you've given us, this could be a rewrite using 'simplified' logic:

```
SEELCT * 
  FROM CC NATURAL JOIN
       ( SELECT key1, key2, COUNT(*) AS tally
           FROM Service
          GROUP
             BY key1, key2 ) AS t
 WHERE key3 = 'new' OR tally <= 2;
```

Not sure whether it will perform better but might give you some ideas of what to try next?